# pass bundle from recycleview adapter to activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to pass a bundle on click of button to new activity.
This is the code for bundle in the class adapter which extends recycleview adapter

```
private void passBundle (Vendor mItemSelected){
    mBundle = new Bundle();
    mBundle.putString("VENDOR_ID", mItemSelected.getVENDORID());
    mBundle.putString("CAT_ID", "" + mItemSelected.getVEN_TYPE());
    mBundle.putString("VENDOR_NAME", "" + mItemSelected.getVENDORNAME());
    mBundle.putString("CAT_ID", "" + mItemSelected.getVEN_TYPE());
    mBundle.putString("CAT_ID", "" + mItemSelected.getVEN_TYPE());
    mBundle.putString("VENDOR_AREA", "" + mItemSelected.getVENDORADDRESS());
    Intent in = new Intent(context,Chat_Activity.class);
    in.putExtra("Bundle", mBundle);
    Context.startActivity(in);
}
```

and this is the code where i retrieve the bundle data in another activity.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    chatVenID = bundle.getString("VENDOR_ID", "");
    catID = bundle.getString("CAT_ID", "");
    vendorName = bundle.getString("VENDOR_NAME", "");
    vendorArea = bundle.getString("VENDOR_AREA","");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke

```
   Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("Bundle");
   chatVenID = bundle.getString("VENDOR_ID", "");
```

in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) method;
new Bunlde() will create a new bundle object, can't get pass value from prev activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
```

In this code, you are creating a new object of Bundle, so you wont' get any values. Change it to

```
getIntent().getBundleExtra("Bundle")
```